# Is this a race condition issue in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Basically I have this **User** model which has certain attributes say 'health' and another **Battle** model which records all the fight between Users. Users can fight with one another and some probability will determine who wins. Both will lose health after a fight.

So in the **Battle** controller, 'CREATE' action I did,

```
@battle = Battle.attempt current_user.id, opponent.id
```

In the **Battle** model,

```
def self.attempt current_user.id, opponent_id

  battle = Battle.new({:user_id => current_user.id, :opponent_id => opponent_id})

  # all the math calculation here
  ...

  # Update Health
  ...
  battle.User.health = new_health
  battle.User.save
  battle.save

  return battle

end
```

Back to the **Battle** controller, I did ...

```
new_user_health = current_user.health
```

to get the new health value after the Battle. However the value I got is the old health value (the health value before the Battle).

Has anyone face this kind of problem before ???

---

**UPDATE**

I just add

```
current_user.reload
```

before the line

```
new_user_health = current_user.health
```

and that works. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: I _think_ this is what you're facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519741/how-can-i-know-when-to-refresh-my-model-object-in-rails

Comment: which part is confusing? ya it's actual code but I only highlight the main things

Comment: I edited the code abit, less confusing now ?

Comment: John, in Ruby, classes are capitalized, constants are all-caps, and method names are lowercase (or, if you've not yet shed your Java ways, camelcase).  It's unusual to see what appears to be a method name that's capitalized.  That, I suspect, is what is confusing @sarnold.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a race condition, I'd call it updating the db but not the current_user.

Comment: ya i know, i did not want to copy and paste my code because it is so long, and only a few lines are the relevant ones to my problem, so I type it out and probably forget about the naming. That's y i edited it. Any thanks sarnold, found my answer

Comment: @John: far more understandable, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are getting `current_user`, then updating `battle.user` and then expecting `current_user` to automatically have the updated values.  This type of thing is possible using Rails' [Identity Map](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/IdentityMap.html) but there are some caveats that you'll want to read up on first.

The problem is that even though the two objects are backed by the same data in the database, you have two objects in memory.  To refresh the information, you can call `current_user.reload`.

As a side note, this wouldn't be classified a race condition because you aren't using more than one process to modify/read the data. In this example, you are reading the data, then updating the data on a different object in memory. A race condition could happen if you were using two threads to access the same information at the same time.

Also, you should use `battle.user`, not `battle.User` like Wayne mentioned in the comments.

Comment: That's what I said :) Yours was longer though. (Oh if I had a nickel...) +1 for spelling it all out.