# Delete in Many to Many Relationship Not Symmetric?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two Models, Product and Category, and a join table, Categorizations, for the many-to-many relationship.

Let's say I have two objects, product and category, that are instances of the above.

```
products = Product.new(...)
category = Category.new(...)
product.categories << category
```

This successfully creates the relationship in both directions in the rails console, so that:

```
product.categories
category.products
```

are both nonempty. Next:

```
product.categories.delete category
```

will delete the value from the product object and the join table. HOWEVER it will *not* delete it from the category object, so that:

```
category.products
```

is nonempty, which means that the in-memory category.products object is out of sync with the actual database. It seems weird to me that creation would work symmetrically but deletion would not.

Here are the relevant models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations, :uniq => true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations, :uniq => true
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, class_name: "Product"
  belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category"

  validates :product, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So as for below I've found that if I reload product via **product = Product.find(product.id)** then **product.categories** is indeed **[]**. I don't want to have to use X.find every time I reference an object to ensure that the data in the object is valid; is there another way to ensure that objects are kept up-to-date with deletes? A pub/sub approach or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: it's product.reload

This explanation is the first one I've found after hours searching:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449957/456280

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're observing is the way Rails is designed to behave. See the [Rails Guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

You might also want to look at the section on has_and_belongs_to_many (HABTM) associations. HABTM would let you get rid of your explicit Categorization model if renamed the join table categories_products.

Comment: HI Alex: thanks for the response! I read the guide before posting here, but it didn't say much explicit about delete behavior. So what's the solution if I want the delete to also be symmetric? This doesn't make that much sense to me since creating works symmetrically.

Comment: So one thing that I've realized is that using Product.find(product.id) ensures that I have the latest data from the DB. Is there a rails best practice around not using in-memory objects for this reason since they are in effect invalidated by many changes to underlying data?