# Delete in one-to-many hierarchical relationships not symmetric?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple hierarchy that I'm trying to build.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

I can add categories to a tree and it works fine. However, things do not work as expected when deleting. For example:

```
root = Category.new(:name => "Root")
child = Category.new(:name => "Child")
child.parent = root
# things are fine to this point. root.children contains child,
# and child.parent is root

root.children.delete child
# at this point root.children is empty, but child.parent is still root
```

Any ideas what might be happening here? Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect that to be the case, especially if it was a soft delete.

Comment: Hi Tony: thanks for the help. Is there any way to make such a delete affect child.parent that you can think of?

Comment: I think you'd have to add something,  or reload as you posted yourself makes sense. Personally I'd be concerned that I was making use of an orphan. This would be like Update Orders Set CustomerID = null where CustomerID = 456, never been happy with that sort of thing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: it's product.reload

This explanation is the first one I've found after hours searching:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449957/456280

(Also this is directly related to my question here: [Delete in Many to Many Relationship Not Symmetric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308065/delete-in-many-to-many-relationship-not-symmetric/12318359#12318359) )

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:dependent => :destroy` to the `has_many` relationship, which would delete the children of the parent when the parent is destroyed. You probably don't want to destroy the parent if just one of its children is destroyed, right?

Comment: I actually don't want to delete either the parent or the child; what I want is for the relationship itself to be removed. From a DB perspective, this would be making the value of the parent_id column nil for the child. Make sense?