# Rails integration test instance variable methods not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, cucumber, integration-testing

I'm working on a RoR project with devise and cucumber and I've run into an interesting problem I don't quite understand. I'm writing integration tests (cucumber steps) to test devise and make sure nothing I do in the future breaks it, and I've discovered some weird behavior:

Within a test the following code doesn't work:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@user.lock_access!
expect(@user.access_locked?).to be_true
```

It returns false instead. However, this does work:

```
expect(User.find(@user.id).access_locked?).to be_true
```

So for some reason the instance variable doesn't have the correct information, but when I pull from the database, it's correct. I'm guessing that this is actually the correct behavior with ActiveRecord, but I don't exactly understand why.

Can someone explain why this is? And how to clean up this code a bit if there's a method or something available to make `@user` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This other question [How can I know when to "refresh" my model object in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519741/how-can-i-know-when-to-refresh-my-model-object-in-rails) might shed some light.

Try:

```
expect(@user.reload.access_locked?).to be_true
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the `@user` instance still refers to that object existing in memory, though the data in database does have changed.

To fix, force `@user` to reload

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@user.lock_access!
@user.reload
```

Actually your solution by `find` has the same effect as `reload`.

Answer (score 0):

`lock_access` works by writing the `locked_at` attribute, which won't get picked up by `@user` unless you do a reload.