# rspec assigning variables - ERROR: expected: "Completed" got: "pending" (compared using ==)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, factory-bot

I am testing my controller in ruby on rails using RSPEC and Factories (using 
factory girl)
**Controller Code:**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!
  before_action :set_job

def complete
  @job.status = "completed"
  @job.save!
  Event.where("job_id = ? AND starts_at > ?", @job.id, DateTime.now).destroy_all
  redirect_to scheduler_path
  puts @job.inspect
end

  def set_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:id] || params[:job_id])
  end

end
```

**RSPEC Code:**

```
describe JobsController do
  login_user

  before do 
    @job=FactoryGirl.create(:job)
  end

  describe "Complete Action" do 
    it "sets job status to complete" do 
      puts @job.inspect
      get :complete, :id=>@job.id
      @job.status.should eq("Completed")
    end
  end
```

**The Error:**

```
 expected: "Completed" got: "pending" (compared using ==)
```

Note the output from the controller code is:

```
#<Job id: 12, name: nil, status: "completed">
```

So I know its changed within the controller, however why does it go back to "pending" in factory girl ? Note 2: Pending is the default value.
Am i mis-understanding the relationship between the controller and factory girl ?

Help please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many things going on here.

Firstly, you can't expect `Completed` with a capital `C` when the status is being set to `completed` with a small case `c`.

Secondly, there are two `puts @job.inspect` lines - one in the controller and one in the test; make sure you are able to differentiate between the output of the two.

Lastly, in the controller test, after the `get` statement, you need a `@job.reload` to make sure the `@job` object is updated from the database. Without the `@job.reload`, you are still seeing the original value of `@job.status` - which is being correctly set to `pending` (I assume by the factory)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449957/429758 for a fuller explanation for why `@job.reload` is required.

The full controller test would be as follows:

```
describe "Complete Action" do 
  it "sets job status to complete" do 
    @job.status.should eq("pending") # Optionally check the original status
    get :complete, :id=>@job.id
    @job.reload
    @job.status.should eq("completed")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try reloading the `@job`:

```
@job.reload.status.should eq "completed"
```

Note that I've changed `Completed` to `completed` in your expected string.

#### Side note

Besides that, I noticed that you've used a `before_action` to retrieve the job, which could be done differently. You're also not checking whether the job was saved or not and always redirecting to the `scheduler_path`. You might want to change that. I would personally do something like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!

  def complete
    if job.update_attributes status: :completed
      Event.where("job_id = ? AND starts_at > ?", job.id, DateTime.now).destroy_all
      redirect_to scheduler_path
    else
      # do something else, perhaps redirect to scheduler_path with an alert?
    end
  end

  def job
    @job ||= Job.find(params[:id] || params[:job_id])
  end

end
```